# counter is not incremented in setTimeout in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, settimeout, event-loop

In the below program in Node.js loop is executed many times but why control is not coming out from loop. I did not forgot to do i++ in for, I incremented the value of i in setTimeout.

```
function abc () {
  for(var i=0;i<5;) {
    console.log("executes loop");
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(i++);
    },0)
  }
}

abc();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `i++` in loop.

Try this

```html
<html>
<body>
 


 <script>
  window.onload = function function_name(argument) {
   // body...

  function abc () {
   for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    console.log("executes loop");
    setTimeout(function(){
     console.log(i++);
    },0)
   }
  }

  abc();
  }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Due to timeout it is going out of the loop, so that when it will return on that value of `i` will be 5, so it will print after 5.

**Edited**

If you want to increment value inside `timeout`

Try this

```html
<html>
<body>
 


 <script>
  window.onload = function function_name(argument) {
   // body...

  var j = 0;

  function abc () {
   for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    console.log("executes loop");
    setTimeout(function(){
     i++;
     j = i-6;
     console.log(j);
    },0)
   }
  }

  abc();
  }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ,Actually I don not want to increment value of i in for syntax. I want to increment value in setTimeout and I want the reason why i is not incrementing in setTimeout and also why the value of i is not printing.

Comment: @SushilKumar edited my answer now check

Comment: for(var i=0;i<5;) do not increment i in for loop